# WKWebView best way to check if URL has SSL and show lock-icon beneath url in text field

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, wkwebview

I'm trying to make an app kinda like Safari, where if a domain has SSL-encryption, it should make this clear for the user by setting the host url to a green color.

However, is there a built-in method for checking this, or should I just check for a prefix https?

I can do this with the following code, but is there a better way? Can you also tell me how I can display the Lock icon to the left of the text? (Not as an image, but label with font icon type)

```
// Check if host has SSL-encryption and display secure lock to notify user
    if (navigationAction.request.mainDocumentURL?.absoluteString.hasPrefix("https://"))!{
        textFieldURL.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4666666687, green: 0.7647058964, blue: 0.2666666806, alpha: 1)
    }else{
        textFieldURL.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    }
```

Comment: A website address can have HTTPS and be insecure for many reasons. See https://badssl.com/ for examples of these situations. Also, a website can have an Extended Validation (EV) Certificate, which most browsers show as the lock icon followed by the company name.

Comment: Implementing the delegate methods in `WKNavigationDelegate` such as `didCommit`, `didFailProvisionalNavigation`, and `didFail` should be a good starting point. There is a property of the `WKWebView` called `hasOnlySecureContent` which should, when queried at the correct moment, tell you whether the current contents of the web view are secure or not.

Comment: @paulvs Yeah, that crossed my mind, that's why I started this question.

Comment: And thanks, I'll take a look at that info.

Answer (score 1):

WkWebView has a ServerTrust property that can tell you the status of the currently committed navigation.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1791920-servertrust?language=objc

```
// Verify that trust.
SecTrustResultType trustResult;
SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &trustResult);
```